# fbtorch: cmake can not find torch directories

Tags: cmake, torch

I am trying to build and install fbtorch, however when I used cmake I got the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (FIND_PACKAGE):
  By not providing "FindTorch.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Torch", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Torch" with any of
  the following names:

    TorchConfig.cmake
    torch-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Torch" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Torch_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Torch"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

I searched online and found some solutions such as using

```
source ~/torch/install/bin/torch-activate
```

or reinstalling torch, but nothing helps.
Could someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: There is should be file `TorchConfig.cmake`, which comes with *torch* installation. Where is this file located on your machine?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I found two TorchConfig.cmake. One at install/share/cmake/torch, and the other one at pkg/torch/build/cmake-exports

Comment: As error message suggests, set variable *Torch_DIR* to directory containing that file. E.g., when calling cmake: `cmake -DTorch_DIR=install/share/cmake/torch ...`

Answer (score 4):

Got the same issue.

Solution: export `Torch_DIR` as env variable before cmake

e.g. i am using python virtual env on linux, and installed pytorch using 'pip'.

```
export Torch_DIR=/home/my/pyenv/py3.7-torch1.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/share/cmake/Torch

cmake blablabla
make
```

Answer (score 1):

if use clion:

> clion preference --> Environment ---> /some_path_to/torchscript/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch