# How to add libtorch library to CLION?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, libtorch

I am trying to get started with DeepLearning using libtorch, pytorch's C++ version on my Windows machine.

However, problems have been arising throughout the installation process:
Namely, I cannot seem to find my libtorch-library inside clion.

The error message I get is:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindTorch.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Torch", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Torch" with any of
  the following names:

    TorchConfig.cmake
    torch-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Torch" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Torch_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Torch"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

I am a little ashamed to even ask this question, because it looks like the error message is very descriptive, but I have been trying for a couple of hours now and cannot solve it.
So far I have tried:

- Adding Environment Variables
- Setting Module Path (unsuccessfully)
- unzipping the library directly into the project directory
- some other cmake stuff

It looks like there is a very simple solution to this using cmake, however, I am fairly new to cmake, so I hope someone can help me in a way I can understand.

EDIT:
Okay, I was able to fix it with all of your help, thank you guys and especially @drescherjm helping out my cmake-illiterate butt.

Comment: Do either of these `TorchConfig.cmake` or `torch-config.cmake` files exist?

Comment: It could be an overlook in your question, but you did not mention the one place that the error message is telling you about: `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. Did you do that?

Comment: After googling, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623184/fbtorch-cmake-can-not-find-torch-directories) post, which suggests in the comments to locate the  `TorchConfig.cmake` file on your machine, and set the `Torch_DIR` CMake variable to the location containing that file: e.g. `cmake -DTorch_DIR=C:/path/to/libtorch/cmake ......` Did you try this?

Comment: ***unzipping the library directly into the project directory*** Does this mean you did not configure and build libtorch first? You can't just dump the source code into a folder.

Comment: @squareskittkes As a rule, prefer CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to foo_DIR. This is the approach recommended by CMake (and libtorch in this case).

Comment: @drescherjm Yes they both do exist, however I do not know how to link it successfully.

Comment: @spectras How would one go about adding the library to the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` ?

Comment: One way is as @squareskittles said, set the `CMake` variable `Torch_DIR` to the full path of the folder containing either of those files.

Comment: For your last comment its not about adding a library its about putting the fulll path of the folder containing either of those cmake files in that CMake variable.

Comment: @squareskittles I tried, but it did not work. Am I correct in the assumption that this command is something you would run a single time in the power shell or some other shell?

Comment: You can run that a single time at configure stage.

Comment: @drescherjm So the CMAKE code would look like `set(${Torch_DIR} "c:/foo/bar")`? Is this correct?

Comment: `set(Torch_DIR "c:/foo/bar")` before the find_package() could work but I prefer to use `cmake -D` like @squareskittles showed or cmake-gui and add the variable in the GUI

Comment: In `CLion` the CMake options seems like a place should be able to set this variable. [https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/cmake-profile.html#cmake-generators](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/cmake-profile.html#cmake-generators) there is an example with `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=` a little down the page.

Comment: @greilchri If you found a solution to the issue, please consider writing an answer post explaining/showing how you resolved the problem. This way, other viewers can learn how you fixed the issue and benefit from your post.

Answer (score 1):

this is my CMakeLists.txt and  it works:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(libtorch_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
add_executable(libtorch_test main.cpp)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /home/myhost/device/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch)

find_package( Torch REQUIRED )
```

key point for the issue is that set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH as your/path//libtorch/share/cmake/Torch

Comment: Succeffuly build . But when it type include "torch/torch.h", CLion Editor doesn't find the library

Comment: never hardcode local paths within your `CMakeLists.txt`

Answer (score 0):

The error instructs you to

> set "Torch_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files`.

You can set one by passing it as a command line argument:
`cmake .. -G Ninja -DTorch_DIR="path_to_your_local_torch_dir`
**Do NOT include your local paths within your CMakeLists.txt like the other answers suggest you to.**